# How to change Samba idmap mathetically for all files and folders in order to keep ACLs and perms?

Tags: active-directory, samba, truenas

I've got an old FreeNAS 9.2 system that has a bunch of Windows shares authenticated via Active Directory services. At some point, the IDMAP by default was changed in TrueNAS for Samba/AD integrations, [apparently to fix a bug](https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/different-idmap-ranges-between-11-x-and-12.89296/). In the version of FreeNAS I have it's currently thus:

[image: current idmap]

and in the new installation of TrueNAS 12, it's thus:

[image]

I would like to upgrade the system to TrueNAS 12 (and move it to better hardware), but I would also really like to keep all the ACLs and perms in place. Is there a way to mathematically change all the RIDs in the all the files in a share on FreeNAS to bump them up to the new range?

Thank you and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.  I'll just copy and paste from an email sent to me by one of the members of the Samba team:

> Oh yes, if you use the winbind 'rid' backend (as in 'idmap config
> DOMAIN : backend = rid'), then the user or group RID, with the low
> range you set in smb.conf , is used to calculate the user or group ID.
> If the RID is 1107 and the low range is 10000, the calculation would
> be:
>
> ID = 1107 - BASE_RID + 10000
>
> The BASE_RID is 0 by default, so this becomes
>
> ID = 1107 + 10000
>
> Which is
>
> ID = 11107